# Unable to create a user in mac Os 11.3.1 when installing new postgres for first time

Tags: postgresql, macos, psql

I'm using Mac os 11.3.1 but unable to get in psql console at all everything to get in the psql console doesn't seem working everytime it throw an error `psql: error: FATAL:  role "ksh" does not exist`

`createuser: error: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  role "ksh" does not exist`

It seems like that brew does not create a default user for the postgres while installing it

Can anyone help me with this issue or anyone facing the same?

Comment: It means you are logged in as the user "ksh" in the MacOS shell. `psql` (and all other command line programs)  use the current operating system user as the default database user when you don't specify one. Use `psql -U postgres`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this doesn't work it throw me this error `psql: error: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have used this multiple time but it doesn't seem working on the new macOS

Comment: Then your installation is either broken or non-standard. Maybe you created a different superuser during installation? The name of the superuser can be specified when running `initdb`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have simply used `brew install postgres` and haven't specified the superuser